# How can I make a shiny edge material in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

Is there a way to replicate this pseudo-shiny effect that appears on Sonic from Sonic Generations in cycles?

[image: Sonic] [Image Link](http://s.pro-gmedia.com/videogamer/media/images/xbox360/sonic_generations/screens/sonic_generations_18.jpg)

Comment: Are you talking about the rings? That is just a simple glossy material with reflections. See here https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/glossy.html

Comment: I was referring to Sonic himself. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Ah yes, I misread your title, sorry about that. The answer bellow seems to cover it well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is Sonic's basic material setup.
The trick is Fresnel with a little help from AO.

[image: Here is Sonic's basic material setup]