# How to make a super sonic material in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

[image]

I am trying to make a shader like the yellow shader below but can’t get it right. I have tried using a mix shader with two diffuse and a fresnel but it ends up way off from the what I’m trying to achieve.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56437/how-can-i-make-a-shiny-edge-material-in-cycles

Comment: Duarte Farrajota Ramos this is not the same question neither is “how to make a sonic shader”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the principled shader. It also looks like some anistropy is being used but you will have to play with that. Mess around with the anistropic sliders and roughness to get the desired look. It almost looks like your image has hair the same color as skin so its giving it that sheen look.

The 2nd shader is so you can control the fresnel (the lighter yellow part).

[image]

Comment: What lighting did you use?

Comment: Just an HDRI from HDRIhaven.com, not sure which one, I didn't save the file.